# use yield inside another yield

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

I would like to use generator to print the content of an array, however yield inside another yield is confusing to me

```js
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

function* line(array){
  yield "my array"
  array.forEach(function*(v){yield v})
}

console.log(Array.from(line(myArray)))
```

is there a way to print the "a", "b" and "c" each in a new line with the code above?

expected output

```
my array
a
b
c
```

Comment: Protip: _don't use `Array.prototype.forEach`: it's slow, old, and _busted_. Use `for(of)` instead.

Comment: @Dai like this I have only one line to print

Comment: Well, let's move the goal posts, why don't we :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Being explicit, with a visible inner `for(of)`:

```js
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

function* line(array) {
  yield "my array";

  for( const ch of array ) {
    yield ch;
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(line(myArray)))
```

### Using implicit iteration with `yield*`:

```js
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

function* line(array) {
  yield "my array";
  yield* array;
}

console.log(Array.from(line(myArray)))
```

...basically, `yield* $iterable;` is the same thing as doing `for( const v of $iterable ) yield v;`.

Comment: recalling the pointers in C++ ))

Comment: @serge The asterisk has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's `yield*`

```js
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

function* line(array){
  yield "my array"
  yield* array
}

console.log(Array.from(line(myArray)))
```